# Creating menu in html and css

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to create menu like this:

[image: Menu]

I want to see red square on acitve page and after hover. Menu is created by:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span><a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>About</span><a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span><a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to create this for 2 hours and nothing:( Can you give me an advice?

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or show your current CSS?

Comment: Please close your <a>-Tag! It have to be a </a> after the </span>

Comment: the main problem for me is that this red square is bigger then menu. I cannot show it in a proper way. In every case it begins at the same height as this grafient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working jsfiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/6sCZh/

```
li { list-style: none; float: left; background: url(http://getpersonas.cdn.mozilla.net/static/9/0/66090/preview_small.jpg) repeat-x; background-position: 0px 10px;   }

ul {  }

li a { display: block;   color: #fff; text-decoration: none; margin: 14px;   }

li a.active, li a:hover {  background-color: brown;  padding: 11px; margin: 3px; }
```

I've added a css class "active", which should be set server-sided with your php code or by setting it static in the html markup. Unfortunately I don't know a better way. Also a "clear"-tag would be nice because of the float :)

But maybe it helps a bit ;-)

Comment: Thank's a lot. I had more complicated situation but example helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to give your anchor tags (or, better, their parent li elements) a class when they are selected.

Then create a rule that targets li.selected and li:hover which places the red box.

I cannot be more specific without seeing your HTML **AND** CSS.

Answer (score 0):

For the gradient you'll need CSS3 or image.  I used gradient generator for the demo - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ 
The idea is the active link to be higher that the menu and with negative top and bottom margins which compensate for the height difference. And don't put `overflow: hidden` to the menu :)

http://jsfiddle.net/23zZE/